# What is the best practise to protect messages in chat apps?

Tags: socket.io, chat

I'm wondering what is the best practice to send protect messages in chat apps. I would like to check if a user is able to send a message to another user.

I have an idea of how to do it:

- create (jwt token / redis list) and the value is a list of users which we can send messages and check every message

Do you have any better ideas to solve this?

Comment: Depends on what you want to protect from.

Comment: I wouldn't that user A send message to user B and user B got this message if user A doesn't have permissions to user B.

Comment: JWT is not needed here, I think. Just keep the list on the server.

Comment: Do you think that redis will be ok? I'm scaling my app so shared memory is needed.

Comment: Redis should serve for now, but maybe another data-structure, not the list.

Comment: Sergio, what do you think about sets? (sadd)